# How to make an abstract and specific exceptions that raises only with concrete error codes?

Tags: python, exception

I request some api and want to handle its response. I would like to catch any bad responses with abstract exception:

```
class AbstractException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code, msg):
        self.code = code
        super().__init__(msg)
```

And also I want to catch some bad responses with other special exception:

```
class SomethingDoesNotExists(Exception):
    pass
```

I've tried the following approach:

```
class AbstractException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, code, msg):
        if code == 39:
            raise SomethingDoesNotExists
        self.code = code
        super().__init__(msg)
```

And this can work, but one of my purposes wasn't satisfied: I want to have  an opportunity to catch exceptions with any codes by AbstractException (include when *code=39*):

```
try:
   pass
except AbstractException:
   pass
```

But now exceptions with *code=39* can be catched only by SomethingDoesNotExists.

---

Is there simple and pythonic way to do this?

Comment: Make `SomethingDoesNotExist` a subclass of `AbstractException`.

Comment: In program I want to always raise the AbstractException. But if the AbstractException has code, that equals for example 39, than i want to have an opportunity to catch it by any of SomethingDoesNotExists or AbstractException

Comment: If `SomethingDoesNotExist` is a subclass of `AbstractException`, then it can be caught by specifying either of them in the `except` clause. Just make sure to override the `__init__` method of `SomethingDoesNotExist`, otherwise you're stuck in infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks! It is really working for me!